# Moving one array into json objects defined in another array - JOLT Transformation

Tags: jolt

I have my input defined as

```
{
    "lineId": "1",
    "Collection": {
        "services": [
            {
                "Code": "TB",
                "Type": [
                    "Data"
                ]
            },
            {
                "Code": "MAGTB",
                "Type": [
                    "Data"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "promotions": [
        {
            "Id": "1"
        },
        {
            "Id": "2"
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to get my output as

```
{
    "lineId": "1",
    "Collection": {
        "services": [
            {
                "Code": "TB",
                "Type": [
                    "Data"
                ],
                "promotions": [
                    {
                        "Id": "1"
                    },
                    {
                        "Id": "2"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "Code": "TB2",
                "Type": [
                    "Data"
                ],
                "promotions": [
                    {
                        "Id": "1"
                    },
                    {
                        "Id": "2"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

I am new to JOLT. And I'm having trouble navigating to the second array from inside the first.

Incomplete transformation that I tried:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Collection": {
        "services": {
     
          "*": "Collection.services[].&",
          "@(3,lineId)": "lineId",
          "@(3,promotions)":{
            "*":
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

edit: Tried this now

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Collection": {
        "services": {
          "*": "Collection.services[]",
          //  "*": "&",
          "@(3,lineId)": "lineId",
          "@(3,promotions)": {
            "*": {
              "Id": "Id"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I just have to figure out a way to move the Id list inside the objects in services array.

edit2:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Collection": {
        "services": {
          "*": {
            "*": "Collection.services[&1].&",
            "@(3,lineId)": "Collection.services[&1].lineId",
            "@(3,promotions)": "Collection.services[&1].promotions"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the spec you're looking for?

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "lineId": "lineId",
      "Collection": {
        "services": {
          "*": {
            "@(3,promotions)": "Collection.services[&1].promotions",
            "*": "Collection.services[&1].&"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.